# Safari - iOS 13.5.1 - Referrer Policy Issue

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, referrer-policy

Prior to 13.5.1 update on iOS, we were able to remove some required referrers using `referrer policy = no referrer` option for Safari users. And this was working 100%. However, post 13.5.1 update, we noticed that our referrer policy is no longer working on Safari Browser.

It seems that no matter what referrer policy we choose - like no-referrer etc, it gets default to `referrer policy = origin` value only. Is there anyone facing this issue? (only in 13.5.1)

Example:

Before 13.5.1 update

1. User originates from example.com and visits example.net (with referrer being example.com)
2. User then proceeds to example.org but in this case, example.net has a referrer policy of no-referrer. So example.org doesn't get to know the referrer.

After 13.5.1 update

1. User originates from example.com and visits example.net (with referrer being example.com)
2. Example.net has the same (unchanged code) of referrer policy = no referrer and after user clicks to visit example.org, the referrer which should be blanked out is still passed as 'example.com'.

Tried checking out apple discussion forum, webkit update (if any) and googling in general - but no luck.